# How can I compile function with Apply?

Tags: function-construction, compile

For example, I tried to compile this function but Mathematica gives "The only function arguments supported are Times, Plus, or List", I have no a way to compile this.

```
isPrime = Compile[{{n, _Integer}},
  And @@ (Mod[n, #] != 0 & /@ Range[2, Sqrt@N@n])
  ]
```

Comment: You could use `PrimeQ` instead.

Comment: You could rewrite it to a more procedural form, but in this case I don't see the point, you could instead use the fact that Mod is listable and look at `! MemberQ[Mod[n, Range[2, Sqrt@n]], 0]` And use `Divisible` instead of checking result of `Mod`, or best use `PrimeQ` as Michael suggests

Comment: ...why not `isPrime = Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, FreeQ[Mod[n, Range[2, Sqrt[n]]], 0]]`, if you insist on your approach?

Answer (score 2):

To check whether the sentence is `False` or `True`, the [`And`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/And.html) function is not appropriate, but [`FreeQ`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FreeQ.html) works best by [J.M.](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/26840/how-can-i-compile-function-with-apply#comment83532_26840):

```
isPrime = 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, 
  And @@ (Mod[n, #] != 0 & /@ Range[2, Sqrt@N@n])]
```

> Compile::cpapot: Compilation of And@@(n mod #1!=0&)/@Range[2,Sqrt[N[n]]] is not supported for the function argument And. The only function arguments supported are Times, Plus, or List. Evaluation will use the uncompiled function. >>

But:

```
isPrime = 
 Compile[{{n, _Integer}}, FreeQ[Mod[n, Range[2, Sqrt[n]]], 0]]
```

> [image]